# How to stop Nautilus from using Home as Desktop Folder?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, home-directory, xdg

As of a recent boot, my desktop folder is defaulting to `~/`.  I would prefer the default behaviour : the desktop directory should be `~/Desktop`.

As a first way to solve my problem I tried

```
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir false
```

It didn't work so I tried a second idea : I edited my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. I changed the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` environment variable to `$HOME/Desktop`, which is the default, and also to the absolute path `/home/<my user name>/Desktop`. Neither value make it show, even after killing Nautilus and relogging.

What else could cause this behaviour ?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop` in the Terminal? (You can edit your question to add this information.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question Matthew, because I had the same problem and editing the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file worked for me (that is to say the second idea in your question).

Here is a third method :

- install dconf Editor
- launch dconf Editor from the Dash Menu
- in the left panel, browse to org → gnome → nautilus → preferences
- uncheck the box labelled "desktop-is-home-dir" in the right panel

It did not work for me but I hope it works for you.